Why does \zcref{...} give the wrong type of a reference?
I have a tex file
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,biblatex}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{S}
\usepackage[notcite,notref]{showkeys}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=magenta
}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}

\begin{document} 

\chapter{Introduction} \label{chap}

\begin{assumption} \label{ass}
Let something hold.
\end{assumption}

\begin{theorem} \label{thm}
If \zcref{ass} holds, then
\begin{align}
B &= C , \label{thm:eq1} \\
X &= Y . \label{thm:eq4}
\end{align}
\end{theorem}

From \zcref{thm} in \zcref{chap}, we have \eqref{thm:eq1}.

\end{document}


Could you explain why \zcref{ass} results in Theorem 1.1 but not the intended Assumption 1.1?

I don't know the package details but most likely related to the fact that you are using the theorem counter

@DavidCarlisle I also guess so...

Well I trusted the documentation and found this in the how-tos:
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,biblatex}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{S}
\usepackage[notcite,notref]{showkeys}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=magenta
}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}
\AddToHook{env/assumption/begin}{%
   \zcsetup{countertype={theorem=assumption}}}
\zcRefTypeSetup{assumption}{Name-sg=Assumption}
\begin{document} 

\chapter{Introduction} \label{chap}

\begin{assumption} \label{ass}
Let something hold.
\end{assumption}

\begin{theorem} \label{thm}
If \zcref{ass} holds, then
\begin{align}
B &= C , \label{thm:eq1} \\
X &= Y . \label{thm:eq4}
\end{align}
\end{theorem}

From \zcref{thm} in \zcref{chap}, we have \eqref{thm:eq1}.

\end{document}



Nice! :-) +1 Since the OP is going for capitalized types, it's fine not to set the lowercased ones, but you probably want to define at least Name-pl too. Also, the OP sets S globally, but I'd recommend against that, this is meant for beginning of sentences and disables abbreviation for the first type as well, better use cap there instead.
